# Iterating forEach tag on button click

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

This is a simple online test page, I use jstl foreach tag loop to show my data i.e, questions and options, but i need to display one question at a time when the user clicks on the next button, but the foreach tag prints all the questions on the page simultaneously.

```
<jsp:useBean id="qs" class="com.onlineExamination.beans.QuestionSet"
        scope="session" />
        <table cellspacing="40px">
                <c:forEach items="${qs.allQuestions}" var="que" step="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${que.question}</td>
                        <td>${que.marks }Marks</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${que.option1}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${que.option2}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${que.option3}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${que.option4}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>                    
        </table>
```

How can i retrive the dataset one at a time after clciking the next button, what changes should i do in the above code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly simple. I can't see your buttonHandler so I am guessing you are just calling the foreach loop when you click next? Well of course the foreach loop is going to iterate through the whole Datastructure and print it all because that is what you told it to do.

How about you don't iterate through the whole data structure and either print out the first element in your question set then delete it after you print it. Or just keep store a counter somewhere that increment every time the Next button is clicked so it can grab the next question. You do not need a foreach loop if you are only interested in one item per button click.